# jQuery ui datepicker not working on specific page, Bigcommerce cart

Tags: jquery, datepicker

This might ending up being too vague of a question/explanation but I'm not really sure where to start. I'm using the jQuery ui datepicker on a couple different pages and it's working perfectly on all but one. This is a BigCommerce site so there's a lot going on from their backend and I'm thinking it's a conflict with some of their javascript.

Initially the datepicker wasn't populating at all so I had to force it with an inline onclick. Now it's populating but isn't reflecting my minDate or any other functions, as if it's not picking any of the script. No issues with the other pages so I don't think it's my setup altho obviously no idea what the problem is.

Wondering first of all if anyone knows of an issue with any of the Bigcommerce javascript on the cart page that might make it difficult to use the datepicker and, if so, what workaround there might be.

I'll go ahead and post code altho I'm certain viewing source will be the best way to get a picture of what's going on. For anyone willing to do that, I've set up a test site: [Link to My Poor Not Working Cart Page](http://chunks.mybigcommerce.com/cart.php)

Note: the non-working datepicker is within a modal. Only way to see it is by going to the store, adding an item to the cart . Be sure to pick a delivery date from the product page. Then there will be a link under the product name, "Change", that, when clicked, brings up the modal.

Also: For those not familiar with BigCommerce, anything wrapped in %% is a Global Bigcommerce variable and refers to either a text string or code block generated by their servers.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
lang.InvalidQuantity = "%%LNG_InvalidQuantity%%";
lang.Calculating = "%%LNG_Calculating%%"
lang.CalculateShipping = "%%LNG_CalculateShipping%%"
lang.ChooseShippingMethod = "%%LNG_ChooseShippingMethod%%"
lang.CartRemoveConfirm = '%%LNG_CartRemoveConfirm%%';
lang.ConfirmRemoveGiftWrapping = '%%LNG_ConfirmRemoveGiftWrapping%%';
lang.SelectCountry = '%%LNG_ChooseShippingCountry%%';
lang.SelectState = '%%LNG_ChooseShippingState%%';
lang.EnterZip = '%%LNG_EnterShippingZip%%';
</script>

<script src="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/javascript/jquery/plugins/imodal/imodal.js?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<div class="Block Moveable Panel" id="CartContent">
    <div class="BlockContent"> 
        <!---- Datepicker Not Working --->
        <div id="CartdatepickerDiv" class="ml25">                 
            <label for="datepicker" class="name">Desired Delivery Date:</label><br />           
            <input id="datepicker" onclick="$('#datepicker').datepicker();$('#datepicker').datepicker('show');" placeholder="ex. 01/01/2013" readonly />
            <button class="btn-mini" onclick="$('#datepicker').datepicker();$('#datepicker').datepicker('show');">...</button>
        </div>
        <!--- End Datepicker --->
        <div style="display: %%GLOBAL_HideShoppingCartGrid%%">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return Cart.ValidateQuantityForm(this);" action="cart.php" name="cartForm" id="cartForm" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
            <table class="CartContents Stylize General" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">%%LNG_CartItems%%</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center; white-space: nowrap;">%%LNG_Qty%%</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center; white-space: nowrap;">%%LNG_ItemPrice%%</th>
                        <th style="text-align: right; white-space: nowrap;">%%LNG_ItemTotal%%</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr class="SubTotal">
                        <td colspan="4">%%LNG_Subtotal%%:</td>
                        <td><em class="ProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_CartItemTotal%%</em></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="SubTotal" style="%%GLOBAL_HideGiftWrappingTotal%%">
                        <td colspan="4">%%LNG_GiftWrapping%%:</td>
                        <td><em class="ProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_GiftWrappingTotal%%</em></td>
                    </tr>                    
                    <tr class="SubTotal" style="%%GLOBAL_HideDiscountAmount%%">
                        <td colspan="4">%%LNG_Discount%%:</td>
                        <td><em class="ProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_DiscountAmount%%</em></td>
                    </tr>                    
                    <tr style="display:%%GLOBAL_HideShoppingCartShippingCost%%" class="SubTotal">
                        <td colspan="4">%%LNG_Shipping%% (%%GLOBAL_ShippingProvider%%):</td>
                        <td><em class="ProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_ShippingCost%%</em></td>
                    </tr>                   
                    <tr style="display: %%GLOBAL_HideShoppingCartHandlingCost%%" class="SubTotal">
                        <td colspan="4">%%LNG_Handling%%:</td>
                         <td><em class="ProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_HandlingCost%%</em></td>
                   </tr>
                    %%GLOBAL_Taxes%%
                    %%SNIPPET_GiftCertificates%%
                    <tr class="SubTotal GrandTotal">
                        <td colspan="4">%%LNG_GrandTotal%%:</td>
                        <td><em class="ProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_CartTotal%%</em></td>
                    </tr>
                    %%GLOBAL_InclusiveTaxes%%
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    %%SNIPPET_CartItems%%
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="ProceedToCheckout">
                <div>
                    <span style="display: %%GLOBAL_HideCartQuantityTextBox%%" class="CartUpdateBtn">
                        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Update Cart" title="%%LNG_Update%%" />
                    </span>
                    <span class="CheckoutButton" style="%%GLOBAL_HideCheckoutButton%%">
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="%%GLOBAL_CheckoutLink%%" onclick="%%GLOBAL_OptimizerLinkFunction%%" title="%%LNG_CheckoutButtonTitle%%">Proceed To Checkout</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="AlternativeCheckout" style="%%GLOBAL_HideMultipleAddressShipping%%">
<p style="%%GLOBAL_HideMultipleAddressShippingOr%%" class="AlternativeCheckoutOr">%%LNG_or%%</p>
<a href="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/checkout.php?action=multiple">%%LNG_CheckoutWithMultipleAddresses%%</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>            
        </div>        
        <div style="display: %%GLOBAL_HideShoppingCartEmptyMessage%%">
            <p class="InfoMessage Message">
                 <strong>%%LNG_NoItemsInCart%%</strong>
            </p>
            %%LNG_EmptyCartInfo%%
            <br /><br />
            <a href="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/">%%LNG_ContinueShopping%%</a> %%LNG_OnThe%% %%GLOBAL_StoreName%% %%LNG_EmptyHomePage%%
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modal Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/javascript/jquery/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/javascript/cart.js?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/javascript/jquery/plugins/jquery.form.js?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%">    </script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/templates/__master/Styles/product.attributes.css?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%" />

<div id="ModalTitle">%%GLOBAL_CustomizeProductTitle%%</div>
<form id="CartEditProductFieldsForm"method="post" action="cart.php" onsubmit="return Cart.saveItemCustomizations();"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="EditProductFieldsInCart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="%%GLOBAL_ItemId%%" />

    <div id="ModalContent" class="ml-m" style="overflow: auto;">
        <dl class="HorizontalFormContainer ProductFields"></dl>
        <div class="productAttributeList ml-m">
            %%SNIPPET_ProductFieldsList%%           
            %%GLOBAL_ProductAttributeList%%
        </div>
        <div id="CartdatepickerDiv" class="ml25">                 
            <label for="datepicker2" class="name">Desired Delivery Date:</label><br />           
            <input id="datepicker2" class="Field validation productAttributeFluidWidth" onclick="$('#datepicker2').datepicker();$('#datepicker2').datepicker('show');" placeholder="ex. 01/01/2013" readonly />   
            <div class="cf"></div>                     
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div id="ModalButtonRow">
        <div class="FloatLeft"><a href="#" onclick="$.modal.close();">%%LNG_Cancel%%</a></div>
        <input class="Submit" class="Submit" type="submit" value="%%LNG_Save%%" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Script for datepicker

```
//holidays
var natDays = [
    [1, 1, 'New Year'], //2014
    [1, 20, 'Martin Luther King'], //2014
    [2, 17, 'Washingtons Birthday'], //2014       
    [5, 26, 'Memorial Day'], //2014
    [7, 4, 'Independence Day'], //2014
    [9, 1, 'Labour Day'], //2014
    [10, 14, 'Columbus Day'], //2013
    [11, 11, 'Veterans Day'], //2013
    [11, 28, 'Thanks Giving Day'], //2013 
    [12, 25, 'Christmas'] //2013     
    ];

// dateMin is the minimum delivery date
var dateMin = new Date();

// test dateMin delivery date by selecting a static date like this
// var dateMin = new Date("10/15/2013");

dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getDate() + (dateMin.getHours() >= 14 ? 1 : 0));
AddBusinessDays(dateMin, 4);

function AddBusinessDays(curdate, weekDaysToAdd) {
    while (weekDaysToAdd > 0) {
        curdate.setDate(curdate.getDate() + 1);
        //check if current day is business day
        if (noWeekendsOrHolidays(curdate)[0]) {
            weekDaysToAdd--;
        }
    }
}

function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    if (noWeekend[0]) {
        return nationalDays(date);
    } else {
        return noWeekend;
    }
}

function nationalDays(date) {
    for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
        if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == natDays[i][2]) {
            return [false, natDays[i][3] + '_day'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}

function setDeliveryDate(datestring) {
    var deliverdate = new Date(datestring);
    var day = deliverdate.getDate();
    var month = deliverdate.getMonth() + 1; // January starts at zero
    var year = deliverdate.getFullYear();

    $("#delivery-date").text(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);

}

setDeliveryDate(dateMin);


// use datepicker to choose a different delivery date
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
    showOn: "both",
    firstDay: 0,
    dateformat: "dd/mm/yy",
    changeFirstDay: false,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    minDate: dateMin,

    onSelect: function (datestring) {
        setDeliveryDate(datestring);
    }

});
});
```

**UPDATE:**

**I've discovered the issue is not throughout the page. Now thinking the datepicker is conflicting with either jQuery imodal or still possibly some Bigcommerce generated script. First screenshot below is of working datepicker on this page. Second screenshot is of the datepicker on the iModal which is not working properly. Again, the one on the modal is populating but only with a forced inline onclick and is not picking up any of my datepicker script (excluding holidays, weekends, etc) while the other is having no trouble. Also, note the color difference of the two datepickers...one is picking up my link to the jQuery ui CDN stylesheet (added for testing) while the other isn't. Not sure what to make of that at all.**

**Again, thank you very much.**

[image: Working Datepicker]

[image: Datepicker Not Working]

Another Update:

I have gotten this to work, only way I could do it is by adding all of the datepicker script within the form on the modal page, between the `<form>` and `</form>` tags. Worried about this method though...looks like a disaster waiting to happen. Wondering why I can't just call the datepicker as normal and would really like to see it working with a typical setup. I'm worried this being implemented so improperly and causing conflicts.

Revised Modal Page:

```
<div id="ModalTitle">%%GLOBAL_CustomizeProductTitle%%</div>
<form id="CartEditProductFieldsForm"method="post" action="cart.php" onsubmit="return Cart.saveItemCustomizations();"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="EditProductFieldsInCart" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="%%GLOBAL_ItemId%%" />

<div id="ModalContent" class="ml-m" style="overflow: auto;">
    <dl class="HorizontalFormContainer ProductFields"></dl>
    <div class="productAttributeList ml-m">
        %%SNIPPET_ProductFieldsList%%           
        %%GLOBAL_ProductAttributeList%%
    </div>
    <div id="CartdatepickerDiv" class="ml25">                 
        <label for="datepicker2" class="name">Desired Delivery Date:</label><br />           
        <input id="datepicker2" class="Field validation productAttributeFluidWidth" onclick="$('#datepicker2').datepicker();$('#datepicker2').datepicker('show');" placeholder="ex. 01/01/2013" readonly />   
        <div class="cf"></div>                     
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>    <div id="ModalButtonRow">
    <div class="FloatLeft"><a href="#" onclick="$.modal.close();">%%LNG_Cancel%%</a></div>
    <input class="Submit" class="Submit" type="submit" value="%%LNG_Save%%" />
</div>    
Datepicker script here
</form>
```